# Converting Hex to signed Int in Go

Tags: go, hex

I want to convert a hex string to a signed integer Value in Go. My input value is "FF60" and I want the output to be "-160". When I use the following function, the result is "65376", which represents the unsigned representation.

```
value, err := strconv.ParseInt("FF60", 16, 64)
```

I would have expected the outcome of 65376 when using the ParseUInt function.
Any help would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The third parameter of [`strconv.ParseInt()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#ParseInt) tells the bitsize of the integer you want to parse. `0xff60` parsed as a 64-bit integer is indeed `65376`.

You actually want to parse it as a 16-bit integer, so pass `16` as the bitsize. Doing so you will get an error though:

```
strconv.ParseInt: parsing "FF60": value out of range
```

Which is true: `0xFF60` (which is `65376`) is outside of the valid range of `int16` (valid `int16` range is `[-32768..32767]`).

So what you may do is parse it as an unsigned 16-bit integer using [`strconv.ParseUint()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strconv#ParseUint), then convert the result to a signed 16-bit integer:

```
value, err := strconv.ParseUint("FF60", 16, 16)
fmt.Println(value, err)
fmt.Println(int16(value))
```

This will output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/Z8D_yLmu8N-)):

```
65376 <nil>
-160
```

Comment: great answer, that helped me solve my problem, thanks.